# How to get the MAX(Hour) and The MIN(Hour) for each day in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min, hour

I have this structure of table Diary:

```
CREATE TABLE Diary
(
     [IdDiary] bigint, 
     [IdDay] numeric(18,0)
);

INSERT INTO Diary ([IdDiary], [IdDay])
values 
(51, 1),
(52, 2),
(53, 5);
```

And this other structure for table DiaryTimetable:

```
  CREATE TABLE DiaryTimetable
(
     [IdDiary] bigint, 
     [Hour] varchar(50)
);

  INSERT INTO DiaryTimetable ([IdDiary], [Hour])
VALUES
    (51, '09:00'),
    (51, '09:30'),
    (51, '10:00'),
    (51, '10:30'),
    (51, '11:00'),
    (51, '11:30'),
    (52, '11:00'),
    (52, '11:30'),
    (52, '12:00'),
    (52, '12:30'),
    (52, '13:00'),
    (52, '13:30'),
    (53, '15:00'),
    (53, '15:30'),
    (53, '16:00'),
    (53, '16:30');
```

The table Diary contains an IdDiary and the IdDay is the number of day, for example:

```
Monday --> 1
Tuesday --> 2
Wednesday --> 3
Thursday --> 4
Friday --> 5
Saturday --> 6
Sunday --> 7
```

The table DiaryTimetable contains the iddiary, and the hour.
I want want to get the max hour and the min hour in the table DiaryTimetable for each day appears in the Diary table, If I put this query the result will be only the max hour and the min hour for all the query:

```
select MAX(Hour), MIN(Hour) from DiaryTimetable
inner join Diary on
DiaryTimetable.IdDiary = Diary.IdDiary
```

The result for wat I need will be something like that:

```
IdDiary  IdDay   Min Hour   Max Hour
-----    -----   --------   ---------
51        1      09:00       11:30
52        2      11:00       13:30
53        5      15:00       16:30
```

How can I get this, thanks?

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ca9c9)

Comment: So table `Diary` has a column `IdDiary`. From its name I gather that this is the table's primary key uniquely identifying a record. (You should add this to your `CREATE TABLE` statement.) So `IdDay` is information belonging to an `IdDiary`. Hence `Diary` doesn't contain diaries, but diary days. Yes? There cannot be two entries for the same `IdDiary` in that table. Is this correct? (Maybe you should think of a better table name then.) And for every such record you provide `DiaryTimetable` showing the hours for a diary day. Yes?

Comment: And why do you store the hour as a string? What is the reason for notusing `TIME`, which would seem the appropriate type? And why do you keep day and time separate in two tables rather than have one table simply containing the datetime?

Comment: It´s only a quick example, all I needed to know was how he was running, to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT d.IdDiary, d.IdDay, MIN(Hour), MAX(Hour)
FROM Diary AS d
LEFT JOIN DiaryTimetable AS dt ON d.IdDiary = dt.IdDiary
GROUP BY d.IdDiary, d.IdDay
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ca9c9/7)

Answer (score 3):

You just missed `Group by` in your query.

```
   SELECT b.IdDiary,a.IdDay, MIN(b.Hour), MAX(b.hour)
   from  Diary A INNER JOIN   DiaryTimetable B  ON A.IdDiary=B.IdDiary  
   GROUP by  B.IdDiary   ,a.IdDay
```

Comment: Thanks for your help also :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
SELECT Diary.IdDiary, Diary.IdDay, MAX(DT.Hour), MIN(DT.Hour) 
FROM DiaryTimetable AS DT
INNER JOIN Diary ON
DT.IdDiary = Diary.IdDiary
GROUP BY Diary.IdDiary, Diary.IdDay
```

Then the `MAX`and `MIN`command just use the Values from your Diary Table.

Comment: Your code works correctly to me thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

As in a comment you say that this is just an example for you to learn, I'd like to add another answer.

Given that there are no duplicate records in `Diary`, its two columns `IdDiary` and `IdDay` are the fields you want additional information on (the min and max hour). So all you have to do is get this information joined to the table:

```
select
  d.iddiary,
  d.idday,
  dt.min_hour,
  dt.max_hour
from diary d
join
(
  select
    iddiary,
    min(hour) as min_hour,
    max(hour) as max_hour
  from diarytimetable
  group by iddiary
) dt on dt.iddiary = d.iddiary;
```

Sticking to this technique has two advantages:

1. You show very clearly in your select what you are doing and how the tables are related.
2. This works with several aggregates from different tables. Some people, especially beginners, tend to join all tables first and only then think about how to get to the data needed. This can be quite troublesome. Say you have a table `city`, a table `park` and a table `lake`. You want to know how many lakes and the sum of park area per city. As shown you'd join the cities with the lake count and the park area sum. If you joined all tables first instead, you'd have a combination of lakes  and parks that are actually really unrelated, and it would be hard or impossible to segregate the desired results from this data slush somehow.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su explicación, es fácil de entender   ; -D