# SQL query to reduce,delete unnecessary rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to achieve this

```
ID      | NAME | CODE | TIME                  | Start               | Stop
--------|------|------|-----------------------|---------------------|------------
4B37B930| EV   | FI   | 2017-10-20 08:30:00   | 2017-10-20 08:30:00 | 2017-10-20 08:34:00
3333E8C4| HK   | FI   | 2017-10-20 12:33:00   | 2017-10-20 12:33:00 | 2017-10-20 12:36:00
EF84D06D| HK   | SE   | 2017-10-20 12:37:00   | 2017-10-20 12:37:00 | 2017-10-20 12:39:00
```

from these rows in the same table

```
ID      | NAME | CODE | TIME                  | Start     | Stop
--------|------|------|-----------------------|-----------|------------
4B37B930| EV   | FI   | 2017-10-20 08:30:00   |           |
7AA6E032| EV   | FI   | 2017-10-20 08:33:00   |           |
B59D4931| EV   | FI   | 2017-10-20 08:34:00   |           |
3333E8C4| HK   | FI   | 2017-10-20 12:33:00   |           |
1C4890A1| HK   | FI   | 2017-10-20 12:34:00   |           |
AA246243| HK   | FI   | 2017-10-20 12:35:00   |           |
A99DFF3C| HK   | FI   | 2017-10-20 12:36:00   |           |
EF84D06D| HK   | SE   | 2017-10-20 12:37:00   |           |
1D8C4963| HK   | SE   | 2017-10-20 12:38:00   |           |
0358656B| HK   | SE   | 2017-10-20 12:39:00   |           |
```

That is to delete rows if they are within 5 min and have same NAME and CODE value in the table. Please notice that it is ok for upto 5 consecutive rows to be missing, in this case rows with TIME value 08:31, 08:32 are missing but still I want the first three rows from table 2 to be replaced with one row as shown in table 1 row 1, and similarly, rows 4-7 from table 2 to be replaced with row 2 in table 1 and so on.

Here is a link so SQL fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44af04/1/0

Comment: So you want to look up how to use aggregate functions like `min()` and `max()`, plus subqueries or `apply` operators. P.S. Why do you keep `TIME` after getting the `Start` and `Stop` from it? Should it always be the same as `Start`? If so, why keep it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the MAX(Hour) and The MIN(Hour) for each day in this query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546178/how-to-get-the-maxhour-and-the-minhour-for-each-day-in-this-query)

Comment: How exactly do the IDs relate to one another? Only by time? Your data model doesn't make sense to me, but that's possibly due to the opening post only containing a subset of the data.

Comment: hello everyone thank you for your efforts, trying to help. Currently there are rows for each minute and when combined with more columns with for example different name values, the end result is huge number of rows, but all I need is continuous time i.e. Start: 08:00 Stop: 22:00 as long as there are not more than 5 consecutive minutes missing

Comment: If you want to check the difference between successive rows then you will probably need to add `lag()` or `lead()` into the mix.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu couold use a join on grouped  by result

```
select a.id, b.min_time time, b.min_time Start, max_time Stop
from my_table a
inner join (
select date(time) date, hour(time) hour, min(time) min_time, max(time) max_time
from my_table 
group by date(time), hour(time)
) b on date(a.time) = b.date and hour(a.time) = b.hour
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, I have added a SQL fiddle link, could you please update the query

Comment: for what i remember  SO is not a coding service  ..  and however the free coder service operator  is not my job  ..  if my answer  is useful  you can rate it properly  ..  but the effort for write your real code should be your job ..

Comment: could you help me fix this error, "Unknown column 'b.time' in 'on clause'", this is updated query "select a.id, b.min_time time, b.min_time Start, max_time Stop from TEST a inner join (select date(time) date, hour(time) hour, min(time) min_time, max(time) max_time from TEST group by date(time), hour(time)) b on date(a.time) = b.date and hour(a.time) = b.time"

Comment: answer  updated  .. there was  a wrong  .. column name

Comment: thanks that works, with some modification "SELECT ID, NAME, CODE, DATE, START, STOP FROM ( SELECT b.ID, b.NAME, b.CODE, b.TIME, DATE(TIME) DATE, HOUR(TIME) HOUR, MIN(TIME) START, MAX(TIME) STOP FROM test AS b GROUP BY b.NAME, b.CODE, DATE(TIME), HOUR(TIME) ) as a",

Answer (score 0):

However your question is a bit confusing to me what exactly you mean by reducing the rows.  Guessing it be deletion,  you can achieve same by delete query with where clause parameters also with time range less than or greater than operator.

Comment: "less than or greater than" what? And how should the query know which rows within each group are OK to delete? This is a comment, not an answer, as at best, it suggests a vague direction but not a solution.

Comment: @DurgeshKumar Sorry if it is confusing, by reducing rows I mean to delete rows. for e.g. in above table i want to replace the first 3 rows with 1 row where START is 08:30 and STOP value is 08:34 and the last seven rows should be replaced with one row as shown in the above example table

Comment: Replace in what sense? Literally change the physical data stored in the table (`update`), or just get a different view of it temporarily (`select`)?